# find the higer and lower number

Tags: java

i need to write a program that will get from the user 5 number (a b c d e)
and will print the lowest and the highest number.
how can i do it and use less if-elss condition?
 i cant use arry or loops.

```
    if (a>b) {
        min=b ;
        max=a ;
    }else {
        min=a ;
        max=b ;
        int temp = a ;
        a=b ;
        b=temp ;
    }
    if (b>c) {
        min=c ; 
    }else {
        if(c>max) {
            max=c ;}
        int temp = b ;
        b=c ;
        c=temp ;
    }
    if (c>d) {
        min=d ;
    }else {
        if(d>max) {
            max=d ;}
        int temp = c ;
        c=d ;
        d=temp ;
    }
    if (d>e) {
        min=e ;

    }else {
        if(e>max) {
            max=e ;}
        int temp = d ;
        d=e ;
        e=temp ;}
```

Comment: sorry but you are doing it wrong, you should use `for` loop to do it.

Comment: hint: use an `int[]` instead of 5 `int` variables to store the input. It will make your life easier and your code much more readable.

Comment: hey
i cant use for or array 
i have to use if only

Comment: You could just store the numbers in an array and then sort it in ascending order. First element would be minimum and last element would be the maximum

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to just add the five input numbers to an array, and then use streams to find the min and max values:

```
int a = myScanner.nextInt();
int b = myScanner.nextInt();
int c = myScanner.nextInt();
int d = myScanner.nextInt();
int e = myScanner.nextInt();
int[] vals = {a, b, c, d, e};
int min = Arrays.stream(vals).min().getAsInt();
int max = Arrays.stream(vals).max().getAsInt();
System.out.println(min);
System.out.println(max);
```

Another option might be to use a collection (e.g. a list) to store the five input numbers.  Then, we could sort that collection, and find the min/max this way.  Using some kind of collection is probably the best way to do this.

**Edit:**

If you *must* use `if` statements, then one option might be to compare the first two and second two numbers in pairs, then find the min/max from the resulting three numbers.  I adapted the `min` and `max` methods from [this Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58747/find-min-of-3-numbers-hardcoded) question.  It finds the min and max of three numbers, so we only need to come up with additional logic to reduce your five inputs down to three.

```
public static int min(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a <= b && a <= c) return a;
    if (b <= a && b <= c) return b;
    return c;
}

public static int max(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a >= b && a >= c) return a;
    if (b >= a && b >= c) return b;
    return c;
}

// now the logic for your inputs a, b, c, d, e
int min1 = a <= b ? a : b;
int min2 = c <= d ? c : d;
int max1 = a >= b ? a : b;
int max2 = c >= d ? c : d;

int finalmin = min(min1, min2, e);
int finalmax = max(max1, max2, e);
```

Comment: This is correct(of course) but seem it not the good answer for this question :), should we try to make him understand about the logical about the code, not just get it done?

Comment: @DangNguyen Trying to logically sort five distinct numbers using `if` statements, or maybe ternary expressions, is error prone and not good practice.  The teacher should not be teaching/recommending this IMHO.

Comment: it will work . but i cant use array or loops . so its will need to look like what i did with improve

Comment: @EladSolomon I updated with an approach using base Java code.  I don't recommend this, but if you're stuck with it, then you're stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think streams is like using loops, so make simple:

```
int min = a;
int max = a;

if (max < b) {max = b;} 
if (min > b) {min = b;} 

if (max < c) {max = c;} 
if (min > c) {min = c;} 

...

System.out.println(min);
System.out.println(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int min = Math.min(a, b);
min = Math.min(c, min);
min = Math.min(d, min);
min = Math.min(e, min);

int max = Math.max(a, b);
max = Math.max(c, max);
max = Math.max(d, max);
max = Math.max(e, max);
```

If you are not allowed to use Math.min and Math.max, just implement a method for yourself like:

```
int min(int a, int b) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

int max(int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is initialize the minimum and maximum at the opposite extremes and define a variable to hold the latest input;

```
int max=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int input;
```

Then, you take an input and check to see if the input is the new `min` or `max`:

```
input = myScanner.nextInt() ;
if(input<min){...}
if(input>max){...}
```

Then you just copy-paste that for as many times as you need to take inputs (Usually you'd use a for-loop, but whatever).